# Create dynamic form using JSON data in iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-autolayout

I need to create a dynamic form with respect of JSON data value. I have parsed the JSON data and got data with different controls like Textfield, TextView, Drop-Down List and Switch but don't getting any idea how to add the fields dynamically in form view. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
{
"success": true,
"result": {
"label": "Contacts",
"name": "Contacts",
"createable": true,
"updateable": true,
"deleteable": true,
"retrieveable": true,
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "salutationtype",
    "label": "Salutation",
    "mandatory": false,
    "type": {
      "name": "string"
    },
    "nullable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "default": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "firstname",
    "label": "First Name",
    "mandatory": false,
    "type": {
      "name": "string"
    },
    "nullable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "default": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "contact_no",
    "label": "Contact Id",
    "mandatory": false,
    "type": {
      "name": "string"
    },
    "nullable": false,
    "editable": false,
    "default": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "phone",
    "label": "Office Phone",
    "mandatory": false,
    "type": {
      "name": "phone"
    },
    "nullable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "default": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "lastname",
    "label": "Last Name",
    "mandatory": true,
    "type": {
      "name": "string"
    },
    "nullable": false,
    "editable": true,
    "default": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "mobile",
    "label": "Mobile Phone",
    "mandatory": false,
    "type": {
      "name": "phone"
    },
    "nullable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "default": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "account_id",
    "label": "Organization Name",
    "mandatory": false,
    "type": {
      "refersTo": [
        "Accounts"
      ],
      "name": "reference"
    },
    "nullable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "default": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "leadsource",
    "label": "Lead Source",
    "mandatory": false,
    "type": {
      "picklistValues": [
        {
          "label": "Cold Call",
          "value": "Cold Call"
        },
        {
          "label": "Existing Customer",
          "value": "Existing Customer"
        },
        {
          "label": "Self Generated",
          "value": "Self Generated"
        },
        {
          "label": "Employee",
          "value": "Employee"
        },
        {
          "label": "Partner",
          "value": "Partner"
        },
        {
          "label": "Public Relationship",
          "value": "Public Relationship"
        },
        {
          "label": "Direct Mail",
          "value": "Direct Mail"
        },
        {
          "label": "Conference",
          "value": "Conference"
        },
        {
          "label": "Trade Show",
          "value": "Trade Show"
        },
        {
          "label": "Website",
          "value": "Website"
        },
        {
          "label": "Word of Mouth",
          "value": "Word of Mouth"
        },
        {
          "label": "Others",
          "value": "Others"
        }
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Cold Call",
      "name": "picklist"
    },
    "nullable": true,
    "editable": true,
    "default": ""
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need more than this, but here is a start to get you in the right direction.

A *very* simple approach could look as follows:

In your view controller add an array to keep track of your input fields.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *fields;

@end
```

In your view controller's viewDidLoad (or other appropriate place) add a loop to create and add each element to your view controller's view.

```
self.fields = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; // Clear and init

CGFloat y = 0.0; // field position
for (NSDictionary *field in jsonData[@"fields"]) {
    // create a label for the field
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10 + y, 100, 20)];
    label.text = field[@"label"];
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    // create the field
    NSString *fieldTypeName = ((NSDictionary *)field[@"type"])[@"name"];
    if ([fieldTypeName isEqualToString:@"string"]) {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10 + y, 100, 20)];
        [self.view addSubview:textField];

        // Keep track of the fields
        [self.fields addObject:@{ @"data": textField, @"json": field } ];
    } else if ([fieldTypeName isEqualToString:@"picklist"]) {
        // create picklist and add to view
    } // add more field types here...

    y += 25; // move to next field position
}
```

You will, of course, also need to get the field data that the user enters. An easy way is to just add each field to an array which can be read later.

To access the user data you just loop through them.

```
for (NSDictionary *field in self.fields) {
    // Your initial JSON data
    NSDictionary *jsonField = (NSDictionary *)field[@"json"];
    // Your input field
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)field[@"data"];
    // User data
    NSString *userData = textField.text;
    // Do something with the data
}
```

Comment: That has given me a lot to think about.

Comment: I have designed form but having issue to fetch data from all fields.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you mean to get the data the user has entered? In that case, how do you *want* to retrieve the data? There are many possibilities, so first step is to understand what you want to do with the data after the user has entered it. Once you know, you can (for example) create a dictionary where you store each field as you create it. From there you can access it again when the user is done.

Comment: Yes, I want to get the all textfields value.

Comment: First issue is how do i retrieve the input the user enters in the text field then after i will store each fields in Dictionary.

Comment: A simple way to do it is to add each field to an array. Then you can loop through them later.
Just create an NSMutableArray before the loop and add each textField to it as you create them. You access the user data from the textField.text property.

Comment: Can you please, get me an overview of Source code for all this scenarios. Thank You.

Answer (score -1):

- first you need to identify JSON object so you identify you need UILabel, UITextfield etc...
- Set All Flag In JSON Response something like as dynamic field is editable or not.
- must be your json data structure fix

Other Link: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/637408/Updating-UITableView-with-a-dynamic-data-source

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/dynamically-loading-new-rows-into-a-table/

Comment: read a question clearly, this is not an answer to the question